# Error using devise - undefined method `send_password_change_notification='

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.0

Previously devise was working in my application. Then I pulled changes from my repo and had to reinstall devise. I did:

```
gem install devise
```

However when I did 'bundle install', it errored-out, asking that I run:

```
gem install devise -v '3.3.0'
```

Now when I start the rails server, I get the following error:

```
 undefined method `send_password_change_notification=' for Devise:Module (NoMethodError)
```

I also get the same error when trying rake db:migrate. I'm not sure how to get back to what I was doing before, or to remove the error.

Answer (score 0):

You likely upgraded the version of the `devise` gem in your project.

If you are using a VCS such as Git (and I really hope you are doing), you can compare the `Gemfile.lock` with a previous version to see what was the original one.

Then, either force a specific version in your `Gemfile` or follow the instructions in the Devise documentation to upgrade your app to the latest version.